# vividchalk scheme only displays properly if different colorscheme applied first

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am stuck using vim rather than gvim for a while, but I am running into an odd issue where the vividchalk colorscheme will only display correctly in terminal-based vim if one of a handful of specific color schemes is applied first.  So, simply calling `colorscheme vividchalk` in my .vimrc loads the vividchalk theme with an incorrect background color:

[image]

while doing the following correctly loads the colorscheme:

```
colorscheme peachpuff
colorscheme vividchalk
```

[image]

This is applied at the same location in my vimrc with no other changes.

Setting these colorschemes prior to setting vividchalk causes vividchalk to work:  `default`, `evening`, `morning`, `onedark`, `peachpuff`, `tomorrow`, `zellner`

While setting the following colorschemes prior to setting vividchal causes vividchalk to display incorrectly:  `blackboard`, `blue`, `darkblue`, `koehler`, `murphy`, `pablo`, `slate`, `sunburst`, `torte`.  Note that many of these colorschemes fail as well, regardless of what is set before them.

Looking for consistent differences between the .vim files for the two different sets of color schemes has gotten me nowhere.  Does anyone have an idea on what is going on?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you mean by correctly load?

Comment: @AndyRk, I edited my post to add screenshots of the problem.  A second, less tired look at this makes it appear that the only problem here is the background color.  So, I think something must be resetting the background color somewhere.